# My code which is calculating sum and average of two numbers returns this error "[Error] ld returned 1 exit status" upon execution and compilation

Tags: c, syntax, dev-c++

This is my code. I've read the output log but can't see where the exact error is; I will appreciate if someone can kindly point me to it. The IDE I'm using is Dev C++.

```
int main(){
    int n, i, a, average, sum;
    printf("enter the number of integers to be picked\n");
    scanf("%d", n);
    
    sum=0;
    printf("Enter a number.");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    
    for (i=0; i<=n;i++){
        printf("%d", i);
        sum=sum + a;
    }
    average=sum/n;
    printf("The average is %d", average);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d", n);`->`scanf("%d", &n);`

Comment: @Samson Royal If I am not mistaken the average will be always equal to a.:)

Comment: The actual error message will be before the line you quoted in the output. Please add it to the question.

Comment: @Samson Royal And this loop for (i=0; i<=n;i++){ iterates n +1 times instead of n times.

Comment: Shouldn't you be reading input inside the loop?

Comment: "[Error] ld returned 1 exit status" probably indicates that something is wrong with your build environment, I expect you'd get the same error if you wrote "int main(void) { return 0; }". A program in C may be written in many files each one compiled to an "object file", the "ld", the linker, combines those into the .exe (or .dll) which runs. From the error, it appears that the compiler succeeded but the linker failed. There is no visible reason why it should fail from the code you've posted.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include how you build the program. And most importantly, copy-paste the *full* and *complete* build output into your question. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: By the way, modern compilers are able to detect mismatching format string and argument types, and will emit warning messages when building. If you don't get any warnings then you need to enable more warnings from the compiler. And treat all warnings as errors that must be fixed.

Comment: Samson Royal, you can ignore the first posted answer and all prior comments except [@Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70752494/my-code-which-is-calculating-sum-and-average-of-two-numbers-returns-this-error#comment125080205_70752494).  Enable all warnings.

Answer (score 0):

You're just missing the `&` (address-of operator) in line 4 (`scanf("%d",&n);`). Putting this operator will tell the compiler, the address of `n`, where the value of `n` will be kept.